# Hyperledger Sawtooth: Transaction processor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to implement a transaction processor in javascript SDK based on the following example

https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-core/blob/master/sdk/examples/intkey_javascript/index.js

Here is my code to run a transaction processor in javascript SDK

```
//validator public key
const validatorAddress = '024c512a6d66917d7d00f52fa299a88594915dab27bddbcd2a80154984d7948c3c';

const IntegerKeyHandler = require('./handler');

const startProcessor = function startProcessor(){

    const transactionProcessor = new TransactionProcessor(validatorAddress);

    transactionProcessor.addHandler(new IntegerKeyHandler())

    transactionProcessor.start()

}
```

But i am getting invalid argument error

> Error: Invalid argument
>       at exports.Socket.Socket.connect (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/zeromq/lib/index.js:510:13)
>       at Stream.connect (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/sawtooth-sdk/messaging/stream.js:85:18)
>       at TransactionProcessor.start (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/sawtooth-sdk/processor/index.js:72:18)
>       at Object.startProcessor (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/helpers/transaction-processor.js:15:26)
>       at app.get (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/index.js:62:26)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22

Comment: can you run `docker ps` command and post the output here? and also are you registering the `transaction processor` inside docker or directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the validator address to the url of the validation which can be either `tcp://validator:4004` or `tcp://localhost:4004`

Here's the full code:

```js
'use strict'

const { TransactionProcessor } = require('sawtooth-sdk/processor')
const IntegerKeyHandler = require('./integer_key_handler')

const address = 'tcp://validator:4004' // If you are not running it inside docker container then change the address to this tcp://localhost:4004

const transactionProcessor = new TransactionProcessor(address);

transactionProcessor.addHandler(new IntegerKeyHandler());

transactionProcessor.start();
```

Comment: Now the error is gone but I am getting this message   `Waiting for transaction processor (intkey, 1.0)`

Comment: Can you share the `docker ps` command log, and also add the `docker-compose` file that you used for the `sawtooth` setup?