# Encode to hex string: argument must be a string node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to implement a simple transaction flow in hyper ledger sawtooth, for creating transaction it must  through some steps

```
/*
* Create the transactions
*/
const createTransaction = function createTransaction(transactionHeaderBytes, payloadBytes) {

    const signature = signer.sign(transactionHeaderBytes)

    console.log(signature);

    return transaction = protobuf.Transaction.create({
        header: transactionHeaderBytes,
        headerSignature:Buffer.from(signature, "hex"),
        payload: payloadBytes
    });
}
```

I need to encode `headerSignature` to a hex string ,but i am getting the following error

```
Argument must be a string
```

But the `console.log(signature);` gives the following result `a51d254f0c27f15abb016030eeb9e38b5ee06ee13d28d88ac5f5cc13a2520b42088090a1d1d19d321098996dc980b3f94cfc84ba0399a73ba7cd9ddc9b2a453d`

**UPDATE**

Error log

```
TypeError: Argument must be a string
    at Op.writeStringBuffer [as fn] (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/protobufjs/src/writer_buffer.js:61:13)
    at BufferWriter.finish (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/protobufjs/src/writer.js:449:14)
    at Object.createBatchHeader (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/helpers/private-key.js:82:8)
    at app.get (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/index.js:24:32)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/var/accubits-workspace/hypeerledger-sawtooth/tuts/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is in that line?, Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande updated my question with error log

Answer (score 1):

The error is not in `Buffer.from` but in `protobuf.Transaction.create`

`headerSignature` needs to be a `string`, and you're passing a `Buffer`

According to the [documentation](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/_autogen/sdk_submit_tutorial_js.html#create-the-transaction) it should be like this:

```
const signature = signer.sign(transactionHeaderBytes)

const transaction = protobuf.Transaction.create({
    header: transactionHeaderBytes,
    headerSignature: signature,
    payload: payloadBytes
})
```

Comment: When i try without hexencode i got the following error `{
index.js:40
  "error": {
    "code": 30,
    "message": "The submitted BatchList was rejected by the validator. It was poorly formed, or has an invalid signature.",
    "title": "Submitted Batches Invalid"
  }
}`

Comment: The problem is in the signature, as the error states, but the error you're asking in the question, is because you're passing a Buffer and not a string.

Comment: Here is similar issue but thats in java SDK https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408385/sawtooth-invalid-batch-or-signature

Comment: I'm not familiar with sawtooth, I just read the documentation, and answered your specific problem.

Comment: The upvoted answer said that encode the "Those bytes should be encoded as hex strings."

Comment: java sdk, not javascript. My code is taken from the documentation